# Why do I get length warning when I use a function through dplyr::mutate, when the function works well standalone?

Tags: r, dataframe, warnings, dplyr

I have been trying to add a new column to an existing data frame, with the help of a function that takes into account a 'double' vector type as well as a column of the said data frame. A reproducible code would be,

```
library('tidyverse')
set.seed(123)
b <- sort(sample(seq(20, 50, by=0.5), size=50))
f <- function(a) sum((b >= a)&(b<a+5), na.rm=TRUE)

x <- c(21, 23, 27, 31, 37, 39)
y <- c(23, 26, 29, 32, 39, 45)
XY <- data.frame(x, y)

XY %>% mutate(c= f(x))
```

In my problem, the length of `b` is `4321` and of `XY$x` and `XY$y` is `180`. When I run the function `f` on its own for various inputs, I get results without any problem. As soon as I use it with `mutate`, not only do I get the length warning,

```
Warning message:
“Problem with `mutate()` input `c`.
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

but the results in the mutated column `c` aren't accurate either. My guess is that the length of `b` is causing this problem, but the function `f` only has to count the entries from `b` that fall within the given conditions, so why do I get the warning about lengths. I'd like to understand what's going on with the warnings and how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not vectorized you need to apply it `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)
XY %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(c = f(x))
```

Comment: I was under the impression that mutate works rowwise already. Thank you that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
XY %>%
    mutate(c = map_dbl(x, f))
```

-output

```
#   x  y  c
#1 21 23  8
#2 23 26  8
#3 27 29  7
#4 31 32 10
#5 37 39  9
#6 39 45  9
```

---

Or `Vectorize` the function and apply directly

```
XY %>% 
   mutate(c = Vectorize(f)(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response :) helps a lot!